# Show YouTube Videos in Bootstrap Modal from Dynamic Video List

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I am making an Application using Bootstrap 3, where there will be a dynamic list of Videos along with their TITLE and Description.
The user will see a list of Videos coming from Database through PHP File like :
[image]

When the user will click on any one Video Link, 
There will be a MODAL appearing, containing the specific Link and Video.
The video will be through Youtube. I am using the Youtube iframe

[image]

```
<iframe width="530" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $link;?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where **$link** should be replaced with the YouTube URL coming from Database.

My data list is coming from database using following code :

```
<div class="feed_text">

                    <?php
                                      $get_data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data");
                                      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_data))
                                    {  
                                      $title = $row[01];
                                      $content = $row[02];
                                      $link = $row[03];
                    ?>

                    <h3> <?php echo $title;?> </h3>                                             <!-- Title Displayed here -->
                    <p> <?php echo $content;?> </p>                                         <!-- Content Displayed here -->
                    </div>
```

However, when I click on the MODAL, I am getting the First link video ONLY even if I click on any link from the list. But I want appropriate videos.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.